# SLES 12: Setting default group for new users via /etc/login.defs option USERGROUPS_ENAB not working?

Tags: default, suse, sles

I'm setting up a new SLES 12 server and want to set the default group for new users so that this is not named `users` but rather `<username>` (p.ex. user `foo` would be assigned to the group `foo`).

I found that the option `USERGROUPS_ENAB` in `/etc/login.defs` is *supposed* to do this job, but after I changed it to `USERGROUPS_ENAB yes` and tried to create a new user via `yast`, such new user would - according to `yast`- still be assigned to `users`.

How can I accomplish the desired behavior via `yast`? Or do I miss something?

Comment: did it actually create a group by the same name as user's?

Comment: No, that's the problem: I manually had to created the additional user group myself and had to assign it as default group.

Answer (score 0):

After changing `USERGROUPS_ENAB` to `yes` in the `/etc/login.defs` file you've changed the behavior, as you are wanting, for the useradd command defaults. So, for example, you could run this command as root and it will do what you are expecting:

```
linux-54pe:~ # grep "USERGROUPS_ENAB" /etc/login.defs 
USERGROUPS_ENAB yes
linux-54pe:~ # useradd bob
linux-54pe:~ # cat /etc/passwd | grep bob
bob:x:1003:1003::/home/bob:/bin/bash
linux-54pe:~ # cat /etc/group | grep bob
bob:!:1003:
```

The problem is that you are using YaST2. YaST2 is using its own default group assignment and so it doesn't respect the default changes made to useradd. In the `/var/log/YaST2/y2log` you can see that when I attempted to create the user frank:

```
2017-04-25 10:44:02 <1> linux-54pe(2871) [Perl] modules/Users.pm(Users::CommitUser):3517 commiting user 'frank', action is 'add_user', modified: 1, ldap modified: 0
2017-04-25 10:44:02 <1> linux-54pe(2871) [Perl] modules/Users.pm(Users::CommitGroup):3787 commiting group 'users', action is 'user_change_default'
```

Also, in the YaST2 module when you are creating the user in the *Details* tab you can see at the bottom that it's assigning it to its own default group parameter of users.

[screenshot showing parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t01or.png)

If you have a support entitlement with SUSE you can contact them to see if they are willing to submit this as a bug. At the very least they should be able to put this in as an enhancement request.